# Input decorator value not coming through - undefined values

Tags: angular

I have an @input decorator that is being used to get values from a model. However when I console.log the result I get undefined. Here is my code

Model

```
export interface ExistingSaving {
  value: number;
  sourceId: any;
  fund: string;
}
```

Child.ts

```
@Input() existingSavings: ExistingSaving[];
console.log(this.existingSavings) // values don't pull through here
```

Child.html

```
<div class="saving-details">
    <div class="details">
      <label class="inline-element" for="name">Existing saving value</label>
      <input class="inline-element" id="name" type="text" value="TODO" name="name" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <label class="inline-element" for="name">Source</label>
      <p-dropdown class="inline-element" [options]="sources"   id="src" placeholder="Please select"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <label class="inline-element" for="name">Fund</label>
      <input class="inline-element" id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent.ts
//values are set here

```
this.existingSavings.....
console.log(this.existingSavings) // values show correctly here
```

Parent.html

```
<div>
.....
    <div *ngIf="existingSavings">
    <app-child></app-child>
    </div>
.....
</div>
```

Comment: Show the templates as well

Comment: Maybe your child component is getting loaded before the value of existingSavings is being set in the parent component.

Comment: @DevanshiMishra I do have an *ngIf as seen in the html template

Comment: We can't debug partial pseudo-code. Post a complete minimal example, as a stackblitz, that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You are not passing the property to the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in parent Html 
Update the code with below code snippet

```
<app-child [existingSavings] = "existingSavings"></app-child>
```

And in Child.ts

access it in `ngOnInit()` or any methods other than the `constructor()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the property to the child:

```
<div *ngIf="existingSavings">
    <app-child [existingSavings]=existingSavings></app-child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Compelete** Working example you can find here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssbwyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Though, answer is** already accepted and have working solution, I want to add some important point when adding `@input()` binding in angular for performance improvement. First in Child Component we have to use `onPush ChangeDetectionStrategy`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

**So, `onPush strategy`** does not fire each and every time for change detection of zone. It will fire only when `@input()` property gets changed. Here, note that onPush strategy checks changes of input property by reference, so simply assigning value to property from parent does not fire any change detection event. For that, You have to `reAssign reference of value like this... using Object.assign({},{})`

```
 this.existingSavings = Object.assign({},this.existingSavings);
```

If Browser do not support Object.assign then you can use simple destructuring.

```
this.existingSavings = {...this.existingSavings};
```

**This little trick** improves almost performance of app by twice time than without using onPush strategy.

**Now, comes** for your part of problem..` Your parent app component is...

```
  existingSavings: ExistingSaving ={};

  eventClick(){
     // this three lines just assign value directly so, no change detection fires.

     this.existingSavings.fund = 'PF';
     this.existingSavings.sourceId='Govt';
     this.existingSavings.value = 10000;

     // In order to fire change Detection we need to re-Assign reference of property usign Object.assign()

     this.existingSavings = Object.assign({},this.existingSavings);
  }
```

**Your parent app html is...**

```
  <p>
       <app-child  [existingSavings]="existingSavings"></app-child>
  </p>

  <button (click)="eventClick()">sendData</button>
```

**Your Child Component.ts is...**

```
   @Input() existingSavings;

   ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges){
      console.log(change['existingSavings'])
   }
```

**Your Html of ChildComponent...**

```
  <p>
    child works! 
  </p>

  {{existingSavings |json}}
```